# Passing an enum as an argument in caliburn micro's action

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

How do I pass in an enum inside a message action? for instance,

XAML:

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu StaysOpen="True">
        <MenuItem Header="Arrow"
                  cal:Message.Attach="ChangeArrowType(LogicArrowEnum.ARROW)"/>
     ....
```

ViewModel:

```
public void ChangeArrowType(LogicArrowEnum arrowType)
{
    MessageBox.Show(arrowType); //arrowType is empty!

}

public enum LogicArrowEnum
{
    ARROW = 1,
    ASSIGN = 2,
    IF = 3,
    IF_ELSE = 4
}
```

Comment: You could bind the Menu to a collection of MenuItems, MenuItem would have a Name and ArrowType property.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to pass the [Enum value as a `string`](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions#enum-values):

```
<MenuItem Header="Arrow" cal:Message.Attach="ChangeArrowType('ARROW')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, should be documented.

Comment: probably it was not at that time, but as of today it is. Just for future readers, look for *Enum values* chapter [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)